# Unexpected behavior of the Luenberger observer for three phase induction motor

Tags: simulation, control-system, induction-motor, electric-machine

I have been developing control software for three phase induction motor. The control software will implement the field oriented control algorithm. The considered algorithm is oriented to the rotor flux. To be able to implement this control method it is necessary to know the position of the space vector of
the rotor flux. Unfortunately it is practicaly impossible to measure the rotor flux. Due to this fact it is necessary to calculate it. I have decided to use the Luenberger observer for this purpose. The observer calculates the estimate of the components of the space vector of the stator current and rotor flux (both in stationary reference frame) based on knowledge of the system input i.e. stator phase voltages and system outputs i.e. stator currents with usage of actual mechanical speed supplied by the speed sensor.

My plan was to develop a simulation model in the Scilab Xcos before implementation of this algorithm. At first I have developed a model of the three phase induction motor which simulates the controlled system. The three phase induction motor model is based on its state space description related to the inverse \$\Gamma\$ equivalent circuit. I have chosen stator current and rotor flux as state variables i.e. the state space model of the induction motor used in simulation has following form

$$
\dot{\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{A}\cdot \mathbf{x} + \textbf{B}\cdot \mathbf{u}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
i_{s\alpha} \\
i_{s\beta} \\
\psi_{r\alpha} \\
\psi_{r\beta}
\end{bmatrix} 
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\frac{R_S + R_R}{L_L} & 0 & \frac{R_R}{L_M\cdot L_L} & \frac{1}{L_L}\cdot\omega_m \\
0 & -\frac{R_S + R_R}{L_L} & -\frac{1}{L_L}\cdot\omega_m & \frac{R_R}{L_M\cdot L_L} \\
R_R & 0 & -\frac{R_R}{L_M} & -\omega_m \\
0 & R_R & \omega_m & -\frac{R_R}{L_M}
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
i_{s\alpha} \\
i_{s\beta} \\
\psi_{r\alpha} \\
\psi_{r\beta}
\end{bmatrix} 
+
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{L_L} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{L_L} \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{s\alpha} \\
u_{s\beta}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{C}\cdot\mathbf{x}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
i_{s\alpha} \\
i_{s\beta}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
i_{s\alpha} \\
i_{s\beta} \\
\psi_{r\alpha} \\
\psi_{r\beta}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The motor model includes also the mechanical equation

$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\omega_m}{\mathrm{d}t} = \frac{1}{J}\cdot\left(T_m-T_l\right) = \frac{1}{J}\cdot\left(\frac{3}{2}\cdot p_p\left[\psi_{r\alpha}\cdot i_{s\alpha}-\psi_{r\beta}\cdot i_{s\alpha}\right]-T_l\right), 
$$
where \$p_p\$ is the number of pole pairs and \$T_l\$ is the load torque (in my simulation is set to zero).

Then I have created the Luenberger observer (at first in the continuous time domain)

$$
\dot{\hat{\mathbf{x}}} = \mathbf{A}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{x}} + \mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{L}\cdot\left(\mathbf{y} - \hat{\mathbf{y}}\right) \\
\hat{\mathbf{y}} = \mathbf{C}\cdot\hat{\mathbf{x}} 
$$

where \$\hat{\mathbf{x}}\$ is an estimate of the system state and \$\hat{\mathbf{y}}\$ is an estimate of the system output. Based on symmetries in the system matrix the \$\mathbf{L}\$ matrix should has following form

$$
\mathbf{L}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
l_1 & -l_2 \\
l_2 & l_1 \\
l_3 & -l_4 \\
l_4 & l_3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The elements of the \$\mathbf{L}\$ matrix are determined based on the requirement that the observer poles shall be \$K\$ times faster than the poles of the system (\$K\$ is a changeable parameter of the simulation). My model of the induction motor is based on state space description and the system matrix contains elements which are dependent on the mechanical speed. This fact means that the poles of the system are also speed dependent. For the sake of simplification I have decided to find formulas for the observer gains which depend on mechanical speed, \$K\$ parameter and parameters of the equivalent circuit of the machine.

The formulas for the observer gains \$l_1, l_2, l_3, l_4\$ which I have been using have following form and are related to the inverse gamma equivalent circuit:

$$
l_1 = (K-1)\cdot\left(\frac{R_S+R_R}{L_L} + \frac{R_R}{L_M}\right)
$$
$$
l_2 = -(K-1)\cdot\omega_m
$$
$$
l_3 = (K^2-1)\cdot R_S - (K-1)\cdot\left(R_S + R_R + \frac{R_R\cdot L_L}{L_M}\right)
$$
$$
l_4 = (K-1)\cdot L_L\cdot\omega_m 
$$

where \$R_S\$ is the stator resistance, \$R_R\$ is the rotor resistance, \$L_L\$ is the total leakage inductance and \$L_M\$ is the magnetizing inductance of the inverse gamma equivalent circuit of the induction motor and \$\omega_m\$ is the rotor mechanical speed. The simulation itself simulates direct connection of the three phase induction motor to three phase grid.

As far as the simulation results my expectation was that the observer will produce the estimates of the state variables which will be in exact accordance with the actual values. Unfortunately this is not truth. The simulation gives following results with \$K=5\$ (on all the pictures below following pays: black curve corresponds to the actual value and green curve corresponds to the estimated value)

1. *alpha component of the space vector of the stator current*
   [image]
2. *beta component of the space vector of the stator current*
   [image]
3. *alpha component of the space vector of the rotor flux*
   [image]
4. *beta component of the space vector of the rotor flux*
   [image]

From my point of view it is strange behavior because at the beginning of the simulation (during motor startup) there is a good accordance between the estimated values and the actual values of the state variables. As soon as the transient related to the motor startup vanishes the error between the estimated and actual values occurs which is more pronounced for the components of the stator currents. Does anybody have any idea where to start looking for the cause of the observed errors between estimated and actual values in steady state? Thanks in advance for any ideas.

EDIT:

Simulation results in case initial speed is set to the nominal speed (in my case 377 \$rad\cdot s^{-1}\$) and \$K=5\$

1. *alpha component of the space vector of the stator current*
   [image]
2. *beta component of the space vector of the stator current*
   [image]
3. *alpha component of the space vector of the rotor flux*
   [image]
4. *beta component of the space vector of the rotor flux*
   [image]

Simulation results in case initial speed is set to the nominal speed (in my case 377 \$rad\cdot s^{-1}\$) and \$K=2\$

1. *alpha component of the space vector of the stator current*
   [image]
2. *beta component of the space vector of the stator current*
   [image]
3. *alpha component of the space vector of the rotor flux*
   [image]
4. *beta component of the space vector of the rotor flux*
   [image]

Simulation results in case initial speed is set to the nominal speed (in my case 377 \$rad\cdot s^{-1}\$) and \$K=5.5\$

1. *alpha component of the space vector of the stator current*
   [image]
2. *beta component of the space vector of the stator current*
   [image]
3. *alpha component of the space vector of the rotor flux*
   [image]
4. *beta component of the space vector of the rotor flux*
   [image]

Simulation results in case the mistake with number of pole pairs has been fixed (initial speed is set to 0 \$rad\cdot s^{-1}\$ and \$K=2\$)

1. *alpha component of the space vector of the stator current*
   [image]
2. *beta component of the space vector of the stator current*
   [image]
3. *alpha component of the space vector of the rotor flux*
   [image]
4. *beta component of the space vector of the rotor flux*
   [image]

Comment: Try to run a simulation of the connection to the main with an initial speed equal to the nominal speed, instead of zero, and let us know.

Comment: @trying thank you for your reaction. Please could you explain to me the idea behind your test with different initial speed?

Comment: It may be that the estimation error is not related to the extinction of the startup transient. Being the observer dependent on the mechanical speed, the estimation error may be due to a poor (or wrong) design of the observer at the rated speed. The simulation I asked seems to confirm what I'm saying.

Comment: @trying thank you for clarification. Does it mean that the problem is probably in the formulas for the observer gains which I have mentioned above or the formulas are correct but the value of the \$K\$ parameter has been chosen in wrong manner?

Comment: It can be both, but I will first try with an adjustment of K.

Comment: I have just done two experiments. The first one with lower value of the \$K\$ parameter and the second one with higher value of the \$K\$ parameter. It seems to me that increasing of the \$K\$ leads to lower error in the estimate. Unfortunately I think that this behavior does not say nothing about correctness of my formulas for the observer gains.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112244/discussion-between-trying-and-steve).

Comment: Can’t you measure rotor flux with Hall current sensing?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 thank you for your reaction. In the time being I have been working on a simulation of the control algorithm. Then I am going to use the on the shelf three phase induction motor. So usage of the Hall sensors for the rotor flux measurement will not be possible.

Comment: Then sense stator flux current which is coupled to rotor torque and position

Comment: That is exactly what I have been doing. I have attempted to explain it above.

Comment: @Steve Some estimation error is to be expected. It can be reduced by increasing gain, at the risk of lowering (or losing) closed-loop stability when used for control feedback. You could also compose a design objective where K is obtained to best estimate a given nominal speed.

Comment: @VicenteCunha thank you for your reaction. Please could you explain to me why the estimation error is to be expected? My simulation models an ideal scenario where the electric parameters of the motor are fixed so the system model which is part of the observer is in exact accordance with the reality.

Comment: @Steve You will get no observation errors for sinusoidal signals only if the state-space matrices used in the observer (A, B, C, D) describes the observed system perfectly. A high gain estimator is very commonly found applied to non-linear systems to compensate for linearized model inaccuracies. If the observed system is perfectly linear and described by (A, B, C, D) and you know the initial state x(0), then no Luenberger gain would be necessary at all to observe the system (L = 0).

Comment: @Steve Ammending my previous comment about no Luenberger gain, it's only applicable to systems without disturbances. Googling for "high-gain estimator" yield some papers that on the abstract alone explain why a high gain in observers/estimators would be desirable.

Comment: @VicenteCunha I have used exactly the same state space description of the induction motor in the motor model like in the observer in my simulation. Do you think that also in that case some estimation error should ocurre?

Comment: @Steve If the observer model is an exact carbon-copy of the observed system, and they are both influenced by the same inputs and disturbances, and both have same initial state, then no estimation error should happen, irrespective of gain, since \$\hat{y}-y\$ would always be zero. Perhaps some aspect of your simulation includes unmodeled aspects that you don't realize?

Comment: @VicenteCunha I have suspicion that the problem is in the above mentioned formulas for the elements of the feedback gains of the Luenberger observer, which were derived by myself. Do you see at the first glance any mistake in them?

Comment: @Steve No idea, since I don't know what l1, l2, l3 and l4 are in your system. You would have to provide the state space equations for both the observed system and the observer.

Comment: @VicenteCunha, I am sorry. I have just appended those information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the fact that I have forgotten to multiply the mechanical speed comming from the induction motor model by the number of pole pairs in the observer.

Answer (score 0):

Example observer simulation of your motor system + observer, with Scilab XCos:

```
// Numeric values of model
Rs=1; Rr=1; Ll=1; Lm=1; Wm=1;

// Matrices for states space model
a11 = -(Rs+Rr)/Ll; A11 = [a11 0; 0 a11];
a121 = Rr/(Lm*Ll); a122 = Wm/Ll; A12 = [a121 a122; -a122 a121];
a21 = Rr; A21 = [a21 0; 0 a21];
a221 = -Rr/Lm; a222 = -Wm; A22 = [a221 a222; -a222 a221];
b1 = 1/Ll; B1 = [b1 0; 0 b1]; B2 = [0 0; 0 0];
c1 = 1; C1 = [c1 0; 0 c1]; C2 = [0 0; 0 0];

A=[A11 A12; A21 A22]; B=[B1; B2]; C=[C1 C2];

// Plot transfer poles of the system
poles = spec(A);
plzr(motor_sys)
// 4 poles plotted, therefore motor_sys is fully observable.
// All poles have negative real parts, therefore motor_sys is stable.

// Observer gains using pole placement at 10 times the sys poles real parts.
obs_pp = 10*real(poles);
L = ppol(A', C', obs_pp)';
```

[image: XCos snippet]

Append observer gains to the observer system as so:
[image: Observer system setup]

You will see that, with a null initial state and no disturbances, estimation error will always be zero:

[image: No observer error]

Changing initial state, you should see an initial estimation error, which should quickly decay. Adding random disturbances to the motor system, or intentionally adding modeling errors/non-linearities, you will notice the observer start presenting some steady-state estimation errors, which can be reduced by increasing observer gain, with transient errors (peaking) as a trade-off.

I don't know what went wrong in your simulation, hope this example serves as good starting point.

Comment: thank you for your simulation example. As far as I understand correctly your simulation you suppose that the \$\omega_m\$ is a constant parameter of the simulation. This assumption is unfortunately not in accordance with reality because the \$\omega_m\$ is a mechanical speed of the motor which varies. I have attempted to include this fact into my simulation by integration of the mechanical equation above which is part of the motor model.

Comment: @Steve Please post a screenshot of your Scilab XCos so that I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: I have finally found where the problem was. The problem was caused by the fact that I have forgotten to multiply the mechanical speed comming from the induction motor model by the number of pole pairs in the observer. As soon as I have done that I have received expected behavior (please see the graphs above, where the estimated values are one over each other).

Comment: @Steve Nice, congrats. This mistake was the equivalent of introducing a model error / uncertain parameter to you system, so you involuntarily got to experience a possible use case for high-gain observers. You can answer you own question, so that this question has some official closure.

Comment: Thank you for your help.